# Mono: "mdoc: There is an error in XML document"

Tags: mono

I [modified a few lines of C# code](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/mono/commit/f72fc52) in the [source of Mono](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/amd64/mono), and now it does not build anymore:

```
make[7]: Leaving directory `/home/nico/src/mono-roman/mono-2.10.8.1/mcs/mcs'
make[7]: Entering directory `/home/nico/src/mono-roman/mono-2.10.8.1/mcs/docs'
/usr/bin/make all-local
make[8]: Entering directory `/home/nico/src/mono-roman/mono-2.10.8.1/mcs/docs'
MDOC    [net_4_0] cs-errors.tree
mdoc: There is an error in XML document.
See `mdoc help' for more information.
make[8]: *** [cs-errors.tree] Error 1
make[8]: Leaving directory `/home/nico/src/mono-roman/mono-2.10.8.1/mcs/docs'
make[7]: *** [do-all] Error 2
make[7]: Leaving directory `/home/nico/src/mono-roman/mono-2.10.8.1/mcs/docs'
make[6]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/nico/src/mono-roman/mono-2.10.8.1/mcs'
make[5]: *** [profile-do--net_4_0--all] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/nico/src/mono-roman/mono-2.10.8.1/mcs'
make[4]: *** [profiles-do--all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/nico/src/mono-roman/mono-2.10.8.1/mcs'
make[3]: *** [all-local] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nico/src/mono-roman/mono-2.10.8.1/runtime'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nico/src/mono-roman/mono-2.10.8.1'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nico/src/mono-roman/mono-2.10.8.1'
make: *** [build-stamp] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
Build command 'cd mono-2.10.8.1 && dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc' failed.
E: Child process failed
```

The problem is `mdoc: There is an error in XML document`. MDOC is a kind of Javadoc for Mono. I am surprised that changing a few benign C# lines would make MDOC fail?

Any tip on what is going on here? I also have no idea what XML document this is about.

Comment: Presumably MDOC is trying to process xml comments in the code, and uses the newly built mono for that. Apparently your changes in the System.Xml namespace have broken MDOC.

Comment: *UPDATE*: looking at the makefile, `cs-errors.tree` is created based on `cs-errors.config` which is an xml file. So maybe that's broken, or it cannot be loaded using your modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial analysis I posted in the comments seems to be right. MDOC is loading the `cs-errors.config`, and using the newly built runtime. The changes you have made produce the following exception while loading said file:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Element 'FilesPath' has wrong order in sequence (expected - -1, actual - 0
```

This was added by your patch. I am guessing you might want to check `readBySoapOrder` as well, such as:

```
if (readBySoapOrder && info.ExplicitOrder != ind)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Element '{0}' has wrong order in sequence (expected - {1}, actual - {2}", Reader.LocalName, info.ExplicitOrder, ind));
```

With this little change MDOC is happy and compilation succeeds, but I have no idea if it is the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try "make clean" before trying "make" again.